# Kivy Weather App How to Print Output to label?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to figure out how to print the result of the weather from the tellweather () class into a text label in kivy.But it wont work Error:
**TypeError: __init __ () takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**  . Normally the result is "its 24 Temp".I now have the following code:

```
import kivy
import requests
import json
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
class tell_weather():
    url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=appid=xxxxxx"'     
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()     
    format_add = json_data['main']['temp'] 
    print("Its", format_add, "Temp")

    kivy.require("1.9.1") 

class MyLabelApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        label display the text on screen 
            lbl = Label(tell_weather())
        #lbl = Label(tellweather())
        return lbl 

    # creating the object 

label = MyLabelApp() 
label.run()
```

Comment: Have to see the rest of the code but I am suspecting that you may not have `self` setup in your `__init__`, or that your ordering of the args is not correct if it is following a parent class `__init__` structure. just some tips, hope it helps :)

Comment: uum this is my full code -_- its a veeerry baasic im new to kivy and python :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label works another way, to put text there you just should use parameter 'text', so your code should be like:

```
# it's not a class, it's a function!
def tell_weather():
    url ='http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=appid=xxxxxx"'     
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()     
    format_add = json_data['main']['temp'] 
    # print makes output to console, it's wrong, here you should return string
    return("Its " + str(format_add) + " Temp")

class MyLabelApp(App): 
    def build(self):
        # what's that line doing here? Comment it!
        # label display the text on screen 

            # so here we use text parameter that will be equal to string that function tell_weather returns
            lbl = Label(text=tell_weather())
        return lbl
```

Comment: thank u @Lothric now i understand the problem. THANK YOU!! now i get this error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str          what does it mean? thank u so much :)

Comment: @Smugmug _NOD you should convert format_add to string. I've edited my answer, check it.

Comment: Thaanks youre the hero!